# Concat rows into 1 string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 and would like to find an easier way to concat multiple rows into 1 string.

```
PK Column1, Column2
--  -------  -------
PK1 apple    orange
PK1 pear     banana
PK1 honey
PK2 apple2    orange2
PK2 pear2     banana2
PK2 honey2
```

Results :

```
PK1, apple orange pear banana honey
PK2, apple2 orange2 pear2 banana2 honey2
```

It is very easy to use `COALESCE` but it is not available in SQL Server 2005. I tried XML Path but it appends additional character to the end.

Could you please provide me some suggestion ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A far easier solution is to use `XML PATH`

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(a.Column1)
FROM dbo.mytbl AS a WHERE a.ColumnX = somecondition
FOR XML PATH ( '' ) , TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @cols
```

Of course the WHERE clause is optional in your case. And without spoon feeding you, apply the same to your other column and concatenate them. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

This will trap null or empty values

```
Declare @YourTable table (PK int,Column1 varchar(25), Column2 varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'apple','orange'),
(1,'pear','banana'),
(1,'honey', null),
(2,'apple2','orange2'),
(2,'pear2','banana2'),
(2,'honey2', null)

Select PK
      ,DelimString = Stuff((Select case when Column1 is null or Column1='' then '' else ' ' + replace(Column1,char(13),'') end
                                  +case when Column2 is null or Column2='' then '' else ' ' + replace(Column2,char(13),'') end  
                             From  @YourTable
                             Where PK=A.PK
                             For XML  Path('')), 1, 1, '') 
 From @YourTable A
 Group By PK
```

Returns

```
PK  DelimString
1   apple orange pear banana honey 
2   apple2 orange2 pear2 banana2 honey2
```

Comment: Thanks John. For some reason, using XML Path, it appended &#x0D to the end of the string. Will see how I can remove it.

Comment: @user3015739 That is a line feed

Comment: I am trying to figure out where to put the TEXT command per what described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547175/sql-stuff-and-for-xml-path-generating-strange-symbols

Comment: Yeah, I can use a REPLACE function to remove it. Now, I added some new tweak where I need another column in front.

Comment: Cappeletti, you are excellent. I will tweak it a bit to differentiate my PK column. Thanks.

Comment: @user3015739 See final answer

Comment: The code working but the first character is missing. Strange.

Comment: I know why. I removed your ',' because I don't have a comma in my concat string.

Comment: Stuff removes the first comma.  Leave it in

Comment: Further testing, this method it added a comma between each column. I checked XML path documentation and I can't find any where to remove it. Any ideas ?

Comment: @user3015739 I saw last night that your desired results where NOT comma delimited but they were SPACE.  I made a change to the answer.

Comment: The results not the same compare to coalesce function where I can use in SQL Server 2012. I think XML path drops all the formatting if exist in the text string.

Comment: @user3015739 no idea what you mean by drops all the formatting

Comment: @user3015739 Perhaps if you post a better representation of your actual data

Comment: I use a conventional way of cursor to concat them.

Answer (score 0):

When your data is some blank spaces `'    '` in result of `for xml path` you will see a `&#x20;` at the end like `'   &#x20;'`:

```
select '    ' for xml path ('');
```

---

In your case I can use this query:

```
select t.PK, 
    ltrim(rtrim(replace(
    (select ' ' + isnull(ti.Column1, '') + ' ' + isnull(ti.Column2, '')
     from yourTable ti 
     where ti.PK = t.PK
     for xml path (''))
     , '&#x20;', ''))) fruits
from yourTable t
group by t.PK;
```